# Formula for calculating distance with decaying velocity

Tags: animation, math

I have a moving graphic whose velocity decays geometrically every frame. I want to find the initial velocity that will make the graphic travel a desired distance in a given number of frames.

Using these variables:

- **v**   initial velocity
- **r**   rate
- **d**   distance

I can come up with **d = v * (r<sup>0</sup> + r<sup>1</sup> + r<sup>2</sup> + ...)**

So if I want to find the **v** to travel 200 pixels in 3 frames with a decay rate of 90%, I would adapt to:

**d = 200**

**r = .9**

**v = d / (r<sup>0</sup> + r<sup>1</sup> + r<sup>2</sup>)**

That doesn't translate well to code, since I have to edit the expression if the number of frames changes. The only solution I can think of is this (in no specific language):

```
r = .9
numFrames = 3
d = 200
sum = 1
for (i = 1; i < numFrames; i++) {
    sum = sum + power(r, i);
}
v = d / sum;
```

**Is there a better way to do this without using a loop?**

(I wouldn't be surprised if there is a mistake in there somewhere... today is just one of those days..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a geometric sequence. See the link:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html

To find the sum of a geometric sequence, you use this formula:

```
sum = a * ((1 - r^n) / (1 - r))
```

Since you are looking for a, the initial velocity, move the terms around:

```
a = sum * ((1-r) / (1 - r^n))
```

In Java:

```
int distanceInPixels = SOME_INTEGER;
int decayRate = SOME_DECIMAl;
int numberOfFrames = SOME_INTEGER;

int initialVelocity; //this is what we need to find

initialVelocity = distanceinPixel * ((1-decayRate) / (1-Math.pow(decayRate, NumberOfFrames)));
```

Using this formula you can get any one of the four variables if you know the values of the other three. Enjoy!

Comment: I complete Calc, Calc II, Calc III, Linear Algebra and Differential Equations, and Statistics at university, and then I forget the formula for a geometric sequence. I hang my head in shame.  Thanks Arjun!

Comment: @user45623 You're welcome, and it's okay. It's natural for humans to forget things that aren't of daily importance. I'm actually thirteen and I learned the formula preparing for a math competition. :-)

Comment: If you know Java at 13, you've got a bright future ahead of you :)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://mikestoolbox.com/powersum.html, you should be able to reduce your for loop to:

F(x) = (x^n - 1)/(x-1)